# How to use a service with Http request in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to build my web application, I've been always using controllers to make HTTP request, which makes things easier and clear for me.

But for a better code structure, and better execution for my application, I wanted to use services instead of controllers to use the web service.

I tried to make :

```
var app = angular.module('ofcservices', []);
app.factory('news', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var news={};

    news.getnews= function () {
        return $http.get('http://int.footballclub.orange.com/ofc/news?offset=0&limit=5');
    };

    return news;
}]);
```

and the code of the controller :

```
.controller('news', function($scope, ofcservices) {
    $scope.news = ofcservices.getnews();
})
```

Everything seems to be right ?

Comment: "Everything seems to be right?" — Surely just testing it will tell you that? Do you have some reason to think it isn't right?

Comment: $http is async. Just check satpals answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293235/http-data-from-service-to-controller

Comment: You seem to be confusing a `$resource` with a `$http.get` request. `$http.get` returns a promise-like object which you would need to call `.then` on. `$resource` will allow you to do this, but you'd need to include it as a module

Comment: Don't understand. Did you test it? Is it not working?
Would suggest using some success and error call back. And return only data not whole $http service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ofcservices.getnews()` [is a promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) You need manage with the function sucess and error

```
ofcservices.getnews().
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.news=data
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //show a error
  });
```

As weel change `app.factory('news'` to `app.factory('newsFactory'` and call it in  `controller('news', function($scope, newsFactory) {`

You can get more data about [promise in the angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have an error :   `"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ofcservicesProvider <- ofcservices <- news`

Comment: @YasserB. You need to rename your service so that it's not the same name as your controller. Then inject `newsService` instead of `ofcservices` as `ofcservices` is the name of your module

Answer (score 1):

The concept is more or less right, but you should use the callback functions to handle the $http response correctly.

But your controller and service have the same name `news`, which is BAD :-) and you need to inject the newsService and not the module name.

```
.controller('newsController', function($scope, newsService) {
    newsService.getnews().then(
      function(newsData) {
        $scope.newsData = newsData
      }, 
      function optionalErrorhandler() {});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  angular
           .module('MyApp', [])
           .controller('MyController', MyController)
           .factory('MyService', MyService);

            MyController.$inject = ['$scope','MyService'];
            MyService.$inject = ['$http'];

            function MyService($http){
                var service = {
                    var myServiceFunction : function(){
                         $http({
                             // your http request on success return the data.
                         }).success(function(data)){
                             return data;
                         });
                     }
                };
                return service;

            }

function MyController($scope, MyService){
     MyService.myServiceFunction(); //Call service from the controller.
}
```